# add/remove fields missing id's

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some trouble with my add/remove fields code.

If I run this code in [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) and I make extra fields with the adding button.

```
<script>
                 var i = 1;
        function addKid(){
            if (i <= 5){
                i++;
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.style.width = "600px";
                div.style.height = "50px";
                div.style.color = "white";
                div.setAttribute('class', 'myclass');
                div.innerHTML = 'Child : <input type="text" name="child_'+i+'" > Ages : <input type="text" name="ages_'+i+'"><input type="button" id="add_kid()" onClick="addKid()" value="+" /><input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeKid(this)">';

                document.getElementById('kids').appendChild(div);
                }
                }
                function removeKid(div) {
                    document.getElementById('kids').removeChild( div.parentNode );
                    i--; }
</script>




      <div id="kids">
                    Child : <input id="child_1" type="text" name="child_'+i+'">
                   Ages :  <input id="ages_1" type="text" name="ages_'+i+'">
                   <input type="button" id="add_kid()" onClick="addKid()" value="+" />
                </div>
```

Then if I use firebug on the first fields I get this.

```
<input id="child_1" type="text" name="child[]">
<input id="ages_1" type="text" name="ages[]">
```

On my extra added fields I get this with firebug.

```
<input type="text" name="child_2">
<input type="text" name="ages_2">
```

I'm missing id's and how can I add id's to the extra added fields like this.

```
<input id="child_2" type="text" name="child_2">
<input id="ages_2" type="text" name="ages_2">
```

If I can make up 5 extra fields with the button, how can they each get a id like this.

```
<input id="child_3" type="text" name="child_3">
<input id="ages_3" type="text" name="ages_3">
.
<input id="child_4" type="text" name="child_4">
<input id="ages_4" type="text" name="ages_4">
.
<input id="child_5" type="text" name="child_5">
<input id="ages_5" type="text" name="ages_5">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `addKid()` loop you are not specifying an ID for each of the newly appended children.  To get this working amend the `innerHTML` line to include the id:

```
div.innerHTML = 'Child : <input id="child_'+i+'" type="text" name="child_'+i+'" > Ages : <input id="ages_'+i+'" type="text" name="ages_'+i+'"><input type="button" id="add_kid()" onClick="addKid()" value="+" /><input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeKid(this)">';
```

Now your newly created elements will have an ID appended to them too.

Comment: Thank you, thank you and thank you again. You are Awesome. :-)